# Refresh whole parent of expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I can't get a custom layout in expandablelistview to work, that refreshes on a click of a child child.

In the example you have the method MyExpandableListAdapter -> getChildView, where the child inflates a custom layout R.layout.list_out_item (what is some textviews and buttons).

Now I want that if I click a button that the child and parent of that childview is updated. How can I achieve this? I was thinking about refreshing the parent and child, because collapsing forces an update, but other solutions are also welcome.

For an example

```
public class Sample extends ExpandableListActivity {
    ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up our adapter
        mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Map<Ability, Integer> abilityMods;
    private List<Skill> skills = SkillList();

    private List<Skill> SkillList() {
        List<Skill> skills = new Vector<Skill>();

        abilityMods = Player.getAbilityModifier();

        skills.add(new Skill(abilityMods, "Appraise", 2, Ability.Dex, 2));
        skills.add(new Skill(abilityMods, "Autohypnosis", 0, Ability.Int,
                -7));
        skills.add(new Skill(abilityMods, "Craft", 0, Ability.Dex, 0));

        return skills;

    }

    public MyExpandableListAdapter() {
        super();
        abilityMods = Player.getAbilityModifier();
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }


    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_out_item, null);

        final Skill skill = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.abilityMod);
        tv.setText(toString(skill.abillityMod()));

        Button rankMod = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rankMod);
        rankMod.setText(toString(skill.Ranks));


        rankMod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                skill.Ranks++;  
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private String toString(int value) {
        if (value >= 0)
            return ("+" + String.valueOf(value));
        else
            return (String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public Skill getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return skills.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Skill getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return getGroup(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return skills.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = infalInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.list_header_item, null);

        TextView skillName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.skillName);
        Skill skill = getGroup(groupPosition);

        TextView skillPower = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.skillPower);
        int TotalMod = skill.TotalModifier();

        if (TotalMod >= 0)
            skillPower.setText("+" + String.valueOf(TotalMod));
        else
            skillPower.setText(String.valueOf(TotalMod));

        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: My guess would be parentview.invalidate();

Comment: do you try notifyDataSetChanged?  
or use 'invalidateviews()' instead of invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562043/expandablelistview-when-i-click-button-update-imageview) link for a customized `BaseExpandableListViewAdapter`. Using a `List<View>` to storage parent view, when btn clicked, get parent view and operate viewholder.